# CRUD operations Azure Mobile Service Table Service windows phone 8.1

Tags: javascript, c#, azure, windows-phone-8.1, azure-mobile-services

I am new to windows mobile app development. I have found many tutorials like [here](http://windowsapptutorials.com/windows-phone-8-1/azure/working-with-mobile-services/), on creating azure mobile service and adding data to table. But I couldn't find any tutorial how to retrieve data from the tabe back to XAML and perform CRUD operations. Can you direct me to any kind of article which explains CRUD operations in Azure Mobile Service Table Service. Simple example would be more helpful to newbies like me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend reading all the documentation and sample code on the Azure Microsoft site.  Tons of info.

[Get started with Mobile Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-javascript-backend-windows-store-dotnet-get-started/)

[How to use the managed client library for Azure Mobile Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library/)

[Mobile Apps documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/app-service/mobile/)

Using this info, you should get able to get a sample app working, and begin to form a design for your application.

It all might seem like quite a bit at first, but once you have your service setup, getting data is as easy as this code I use in my universal app.

*CRUD calls...*

```
public static MobileServiceClient MobileService { get; private set; }
await App.MobileService.GetTable<Vehicles>().UpdateAsync(vehicle);
await App.MobileService.GetTable<Vehicles>().InsertAsync(vehicle);
await App.MobileService.GetTable<Vehicles>().DeleteAsync(vehicle);
```

Comment: can you share your app with me. I am really glad if you can share your app.

Comment: You can see a quickstart for a simple Todo App in Windows C#, XAML for Windows 10 here: https://github.com/adrianhall/quickstarts